# JOGL find current screen size after the user has resized the window

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl

how do i find the current window size in a JOGL instance. The user would have done this to the window manually here is what I have so far, however this just keeps returning 1920 x 1080. However I want it so it returns the current window width and height.

```
@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable) {

    GL gl = glautodrawable.getGL();
    int newWidth = glautodrawable.getWidth();
    int newHeight = glautodrawable.getHeight();
    System.out.println(newWidth + "   " + newHeight);
    try {
        render(gl, newWidth, newHeight);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(dataModelGLEventListener.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Also the display method has a really late response to the window size is their a better way to do this?

UPDATE: I have done this by getting the size of the JFrame it is placed in then resetting the canvas size appropriately

UPDATED CODE:

```
@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable) {

    GL gl = glautodrawable.getGL();

    GLU glu = new GLU();
    float widthHeightRatio = width / height - 2.75f;
    Rectangle r = dataModelJOGLFrame.instance.getBounds();
    int h = r.height;
    int w = r.width;
    dataModelJOGLFrame.glcanvas.setSize(w, h);
    System.out.println(h + "   " + w);
    flag = 1;

    try {
        render(gl, newWidth, newHeight);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(dataModelGLEventListener.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    dataModelJOGLFrame.menu.validate();
    dataModelJOGLFrame.menu.repaint();
}
```

However this causes the menu bar items to be rendered behind the canvas and repaint and validate seem to have no effect on this, How do i fix this?

Comment: What OS are you using? Can you give us more context so we can better help you?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, however this needs to work on WIndows and OS X as well.

Comment: Actually, a GLCanvas is a GLAutoDrawable and you can get the container of this canvas by calling getParent(). The GLU object should be created in GLEventListener.init(GLAutoDrawable) and by calling createGLU(GL). You should read this: http://forum.jogamp.org/JOGL-Integration-in-Swing-App-tp3870189p3870592.html